# Why is Debian not booting with a GUI, but instead to the tty1 console, despite AMD drivers being installed

Tags: debian, drivers

As the title might already suggest, I currently have a problem where my newly installed Debian doesn't start with any GUIs, despite me clearly selecting them in the installation process.

Interestingly, I already have the AMD drivers installed, even the non-free ones. But despite that, I can't execute `startx` successfully, as it says that it can't find `/dev/dri/card0`, and after that, it tells me that it can't run in frame buffer mode.
I know that this might not be enough to debug the problem, but I am very new to the whole Linux ecosystem, so I don't have any idea what exactly would help. So, if you need more details, please tell me so in the comments so that I can provide them.

My hardware specs:

- Graphics card: AMD RX 5700
- CPU: AMD Ryzen 9 3900X
- Disk space: 500 GB
- RAM: 32 GB

I should maybe add that I selected the sddm display manager and KDE and Gnome whilst installing Debian.

Comment: Debian Stable is ill-advised for desktop users because it contains a very old software stack. Try Ubuntu 20.04/20.10 instead if you absolutely need a system based on DEB packages. If you know very little about Linux, start with Fedora 34 instead.

Comment: Nah, I would rather like to have Debian as it is more private then Ubuntu. So, do you have an idea on what I should do to fix this issue described above?

Comment: You can't just bolt-on a startx command to run X windows unless you have something for it do. Try a Debian based distro that includes a GUI - with your fast PC, you are not spoilt for choice.

Answer (score 0):

If `startx` says it can't find `/dev/dri/card0`, that probably means the kernel component of the AMD drivers is not currently loaded.

You might start by running `lspci -d ::0300 -nnk` and editing the output into your original question. That should show which kernel module(s) are recognizing your graphics card, and which of them (if any) are currently loaded. If that produces no results, try `::0302` (= PCI class for display controller, subclass 3D controller)  instead of `::0300` (= display controller, subclass VGA compatible).

I'm more familiar with NVIDIA's GPU drivers than AMD's, but if I've understood correctly, there should be an `amdgpu` module available, and ideally also in use.

Also, will `sudo dkms status` display anything meaningful, or just a "command not found" error?

If `dkms` is installed, it should display a list of any installed DKMS-managed third-party kernel modules (like the kernel component of the AMD drivers might be).

Answer (score -3):

At least to start with, I'd recommend **LMDE** (Linux Mint Debian Edition). You get the benefit of a Mint style GUI, but instead of being made with Ubuntu packages it is built with Debian (stable) packages.

Be careful when using it that you only install Debian packages, no Ubuntu packages.

Try using the Cinnamon DE. Other flavours are available.

Comment: My "answer" was submitted in the context of a question by someone who is [...very new to the whole Linux ecosystem...]

Comment: "Install another OS" is very seldom a helpful answer.